# Azure adds leading space to variable

Tags: azure, powershell

If I run this powershell code locally:

```
$url = "refs/pull/5625/merge"
$SourceBranchFromBuild = $url.split('/')[-1]
$featureReleaseUrl = "http://$sourceBranchFromBuild.azurewebsites.net"
Write-Output $featureReleaseUrl
```

The output is:

> http://merge.azurewebsites.net

When I run this code on a Azure Powershell:

```
$url = "refs/pull/5625/merge"
$SourceBranchFromBuild = $url.split('/')[-1]
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;]"$SourceBranchFromBuild
```

And then create the URL in another Azure Powershell script:

```
$featureReleaseUrl = "http://$env:prSourceBranchName.azurewebsites.net"
Write-Output $featureReleaseUrl
```

The ouput is

> http:// merge.azurewebsites.net

What's causing this leading space character in the `$env:prSourceBranchName`?

Comment: What is your question? [grin] Assuming you just want to remove the leading space, use the trim operation. As to why the leading space is there, no idea :)

Comment: If I run your very first code example in azure, I have no extra spaces. Does `$env:prSourceBranchName` contain an leading space?

Comment: @AdminOfThings no the `$env:prSourceBranchName` doesn not have a leading space. In the example you see I use the same values (url, sourceBranchFromUrl) for both examples. The only difference is that in the second example I'm assigning the value to a Azure variable.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent programmatically it's not hard to remove the leading space, but it shouldn't be there in the first place :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure isn't adding anything - your write-host is!

Your code is doing this:

```bsh
PS> $x = "xxx"
PS> write-host "aaa"$x
aaa xxx
```

but presumably you want

```bsh
PS> $x = "xxx"
PS> write-host "aaa$x"
aaaxxx
```

Note where the second quote is the `write-host` in both examples. In the first it's before the `$x` variable name. In the second it's after.

In your question it's calling this (with the quote *before* the variable name):

```bsh
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;]"$SourceBranchFromBuild
```

which will write a [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) to the log file, and Azure DevOps will process that and update the environment variable.

You're probably expecting it to write *this* to the log file:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;]merge
```

but it's actually writing *this*:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;] merge
```

Try switching your code to this (i.e. second quote *after* the variable name):

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;]$SourceBranchFromBuild"
```

and it should omit the space in front of the branch name in your url.

Answer (score 0):

@PeterBoomsma Try putting $SourceBranchFromBuild inside the double quotes like this:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;]$SourceBranchFromBuild"
```